# I want to create a block of some selected menu items from main menu in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks, drupal-navigation

I want to create a block of some selected menu items from main menu in drupal 7? I donot want to have all the menu links in a block

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a new (secondary) menu with only the menu links that you want, then use [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) or something to create a block out of it?  Is there a reason you don't want to create a new menu for this?

Comment: I have same menu ie main menu placed at two different places ie one in header and one in sidebar. In sidebar I have to show all the links but in header I have to show only four links from main menu. But i donot want to change same links two times if there are same changes in case I create two different menus. I am looking for some viable method.